# how to create google docs using api in app scope instead of user scope

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to create an app which will use google drive to create and store documents. However I have a custom authentication module and will not use gmail authentication.

The documents that are crated need to be in the application scope, and not user scope.

What I mean is that the app should login into google drive and create docs, instead of the user.

How do I do this ?

Thanks,
Murtaza

Comment: Whose Google Drive would the documents be created in?

Comment: My application will be deployed on GAE, can I get a drive for the app?

Comment: A Google Drive is always associated with a Google account. You could create a Google account specifically for storing the app docs, but you would still need to authenticate as that account to modify or add docs to the drive.

Comment: Thanks. Also is there a way I could use its views too. ex I have a lot of excel sheets that the client will be uploading. I can create an interface for their editing. However it will be more easy if I can use the google spreadsheets interface to show them the data, and allow them to edit the data. Is that possible?

Comment: It sounds like [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) might be more up your alley

Comment: Thanks Will. However if I look at this documentation https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/ it mentions clientid and clientsecret that is given when an app is registered with google. So is this case does the app get a drive rather than using a user's drive ?

Comment: Nope. The idea behind those APIs is that your app has credentials that allow it to access the API, but in order to use your app, users have to authenticate with Google as well. Your app's credentials *and* your user's credentials are used when you call the API, and whatever your app makes belongs to the user.

Comment: Given that all the files will be owned by the app, why would you use Google Drive in the first place? Why not just use the App Engine blobstore?

Comment: Does blobstore allow versioning ?